# Extract a row from dataset based on two strings

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation, expression-manipulation

Say I have  a list as below:

```
list = {{"A_OB021_Mp", "hsa-miR-30b_000602", 23.724894`},{"A_OB021_Mp", "hsa-miR-29a_002112", 30.242905`},{"A_OC021_Mp", "hsa-miR-485-3p_001277", "Undetermined"},{"A_OC021_Mp", "mma-miR-484_001821", 26.052717`},{"A_OB021_Mp", "hsa-miR-380-3p_000569", "Undetermined"},{"A_OE021_Mp", "hsa-miR-453_002318", "Undetermined"},{"A_OE021_Mp", "hsa-miR-485-5p_001036", "Undetermined"},{"A_OB021_Mp", "U6 rRNA_001973", 17.669361`},
```

{"A_OH021_Mp", "hsa-miR-449_001030", "Undetermined"},{"A_OH021_Mp", "hsa-miR-302b_000531", "Undetermined"},{"A_U6021_Mp", "hsa-miR-411_001610", "Undetermined"},{"A_U6019_Mp", "hsa-miR-324-5p_000539", "Undetermined"},{"A_OB021_Mp", "hsa-miR-30c_000419", 25.73165`}}

If I want to filter the list to find strings with "U6" I use the following code:

```
Position[list,s_String /;StringMatchQ[s,"*U6*"]] // (int = #) &;Table[Extract[list, int[[i]][[1]]], {i,1,int // Length}] // (data = #) &
```

which works perfectly fine.
How do I filter via two strings? I wanted to do "*OB*"&&"*U6*" but it does not work. Or alternatively, how do I exclude a certain string? e.g. extract row with a string having "*U6*", except when string "*hsa*" is present in the same raw.

For now I just iterate the above code using the outcome of the first iteration as the input for the second iteration, but it is not efficient for large datasets.

Comment: No Mathematica on this machine to test, what happens if you try `/;And[StringMatchQ[s,"*U6*"],StringMatchQ[s,"*OB*"]]]`?  And have you validated your assertion *it is not efficient for large datasets*?

Comment: Try this: `MapAt[StringContainsQ[#, "U6" | "OB"] &, alist, {All, 1 ;; 2}]` Also your `list` needs a brace at the end instead of a comma.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly different approach:

```
list = {
   {"A_OB021_Mp", "hsa-miR-30b_000602", 23.724894`},
   {"A_OB021_Mp", "hsa-miR-29a_002112", 30.242905`},
   {"A_OC021_Mp", "hsa-miR-485-3p_001277", "Undetermined"},
   {"A_OC021_Mp", "mma-miR-484_001821", 26.052717`},
   {"A_OB021_Mp", "hsa-miR-380-3p_000569", "Undetermined"},
   {"A_OE021_Mp", "hsa-miR-453_002318", "Undetermined"},
   {"A_OE021_Mp", "hsa-miR-485-5p_001036", "Undetermined"},
   {"A_OB021_Mp", "U6 rRNA_001973", 17.669361`}};

Select[list, 
 StringMatchQ[#[[1]], "*OB*"] && StringMatchQ[#[[2]], "*U6*"] &]

(* {{"A_OB021_Mp", "U6 rRNA_001973", 17.6694}} *)

Select[list, 
 StringMatchQ[#[[2]], "*miR*"] && ! StringMatchQ[#[[2]], "*hsa*"] &]

(* {{"A_OC021_Mp", "mma-miR-484_001821", 26.0527}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Select[Not @* FreeQ[s_String?(StringContainsQ["U6"])]] @ list
```

[image]

```
Select[Not @* FreeQ[s_String?(StringContainsQ["U6" | "OB"])]] @ list
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Define a utility function `g1`. It detects if "U6" or "OB" appear in the first two sub-elements of a sublist.

```
g1[k_List] := Module[{c1},
  c1 = StringContainsQ[#, "U6" | "OB"] & /@ k[[1 ;; 2]];
  (*Echo[c1];*)
  MemberQ[c1, True]
  ]
```

Usage:

```
pos = g1 /@ alist
```

> {True, True, False, False, True, False, False, True}

```
Pick[alist, g1 /@ alist]
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \text{+A$\_$OB021$\_$Mp} & \text{hsa-miR-30b$\_$000602} & 23.7249 \\
 \text{A$\_$OB021$\_$Mp} & \text{hsa-miR-29a$\_$002112} & 30.2429 \\
 \text{A$\_$OB021$\_$Mp} & \text{hsa-miR-380-3p$\_$000569} & \text{Undetermined} \\
 \text{A$\_$OB021$\_$Mp} & \text{U6 rRNA$\_$001973} & 17.6694 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

---

Define `g2` for the other task.

```
g2[k_List] := Module[{c1},
  c1 = (StringContainsQ[#, "U6"] &&
       StringFreeQ[#, "hsa"]) &
    /@ k[[1 ;; 2]];
  MemberQ[c1, True]
  ]
```

Usage is the same:

```
pos = g2 /@ alist
Pick[alist, g2 /@ alist]
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \text{A$\_$OB021$\_$Mp} & \text{U6 rRNA$\_$001973} & 17.6694 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

For both cases, `pos` is being calculated as a visual/debugging cue only.